# Vaadin get value of string outside init

Tags: java, vaadin

Is it possible for me to retrieve the value of the string "code" outside the init method and use it in a different method?

If yes, how?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: The string MUST be in the init method.

Code:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    main();
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    if (code != null){
        System.out.println("Code: " + code);
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code you have provided your own class?

Comment: @JamesB Its written by default when you create a new Vaadin application. But the code inside the class is mine.

Comment: Can you add code to this class?

Comment: @JamesB Yes I can. Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the code as an instance variable:

```
public class VaadinApplication {

    private String code = null; // <-- Instance variable

    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        main();
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        if (code != null){
            this.code = code; // <-- store code here
            System.out.println("Code: " + code);
            next();
    }

    protected void otherMethod() {
        this.code; // <-- Get code here and use it
        //...
    }
}
```